# How do we show this result

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

The result is
$a$,$b$ real numbers 
$$\max_{t\in[0,1]}|at^2+b|=\max\{|a+b|,|b|\}$$

It is clearly true, but I can see the steps to prove it.

1. If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign then the max is |a+b|.
   But I can see the arguments for the other part.

This is so embarrassing, asking something so easy!

Comment: Is it related with, is $f(t)=at^2+b$, $f'(t)=0$ then $t=0$, then $f(0)=b$ is a max or min?

Answer (score 1):

enough to show that

$$\max_{x\in[0,1]}|ax+b|=\max\{|a+b|,|b|\}$$

yeah, $f(x)=ax+b$ is linear, so
 $$\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=\max\{|f(0)|,|f(1)|\}$$

Comment: linear? what do you mean with linear? for me, if linear then$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and $f(x+y)=a(x+y)+b=ax+ay+b$ , and $f(x)+f(y)=ax+b+ay+b=a(x+y)+2b $

Comment: a polynomial function of degree zero or one, or is the zero polynomial   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function

Comment: Ok, I am new at Maths, Some concepts mean different in different areas. Thank you!  Are you Chinese?

Comment: my head photo is a  typical Chinese style